# c# phone format extension method

Tags: c#, string

I'm writing an extension method that takes a string of digits (ie. 4083239382) and converts it to a phone number according to the country code:

```
public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string ThePhone, int CountryCode)
{
 string ThisFormat = null;
 if (CountryCode == 1) { ThisFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}",ThePhone); }
 return ThisFormat;
}
```

For some reason, I'm not getting the result I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually getting?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're passing in, what you expect, and what you're getitng?

Comment: No offence, but is this really a good candidate for an extension to `String`. Should every string have the ability to be formatted as a phone number?

Comment: @chibacity for ease of use it makes sense but I agree

Comment: @chibacity: what other design option should I consider. This looks pretty easy to me but I'm new to the framework so if there's a better option please let me know of an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie A class with a static method is one option. My point is that although it is convenient to whack `ToPhoneFormat` on a string, it does't make sense for *all* strings. It's the kind of design decision that has a cumulative effect over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might have something to do with you passing in the phone number as a string. Parse it to a long first.

```
string ThisFormat = null;
if (CountryCode == 1) { ThisFormat = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", long.Parse(ThePhone)); }
return ThisFormat;
```

Comment: This seems weird: why would I need to parse it to a long and then parse it back to a string to format it?? The solution works however, thank you very much.

Comment: @frenchie - one caveat with this solution seems that you would lose some data from long.Parse() if the phone number began with a zero, can you guarantee that the phone number will never start with a zero at all points you might call this code?

Comment: yea, you're right! For sure no US phone number begins with 0 but who knows elsewhere. One way around this is to remove all leading zeros from the string before the parse and reappend them after. I'll look into that, thanks for mentioning it.